# Comparing cells bgcolor in html a table, Using For/If construction

Tags: javascript, html

When clicking on a table cell, the color will change to red. When theres are 4 reds cells horizontally it will display a message.

It works if I give the exact ID of the cells (all the cells have ID numbers, like 10, 11, 12 etc). But I want the cell ID to be a variable in the construction below. Tried working with arrays but couldnt solve it. This works with the ID numbers being 10/16/22/28 etc. But dont know how to get it to check 11/17/23/29 for example with the for loop. I dont know how to get the getElementById check in the forloop. Or is another construction better?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Temp</title>
        <style>

        table {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        td, th {
            position: relative;
            border: 2px solid grey;
        } 

        td:hover::after,
        th:hover::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            background-color: lightgreen;
            left: 0;
            top: -5000px;
            height: 10000px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }   

        td:hover {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        </style>
        <script>

        var a = "rgb(255,255,255)"; //white
        var b = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";       //red
        var c = "purple";

        function check(){

        var xcolor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
        var i = 10;
        var xbb = i + 6;
        var xcc = xbb + 6;
        var xdd = xcc + 6;
        var xa = document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor;  
        var xb = document.getElementById(xbb).style.backgroundColor;
        var xc = document.getElementById(xcc).style.backgroundColor;
        var xd = document.getElementById(xdd).style.backgroundColor;



          for (i = 10; i < 52; i++){

            if (xa == xcolor && xb == xcolor && xc == xcolor && xd == xcolor){

                alert("thats 4!");
                break;

            }

             continue;
            }
        }


        function mouseclick(clicked){



        if (document.getElementById(clicked).style.backgroundColor = a)
        {
        document.getElementById(clicked).style.backgroundColor = b;             
        }

        check();
        }



         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click!</p>
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td id="10" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v10 </td>
                <td id="16" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v16 </td>
                <td id="22" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v22 </td>
                <td id="28" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v28 </td>
                <td id="34" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v34 </td>
                <td id="40" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v40 </td>
                <td id="46" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v46 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post a working code so people can discuss and make suggestions on it?

Comment: I updated the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easier with adding a CSS class with the expected `background-color` and then comparing if a table row has four cells with that class.

This approach makes the logic easier to control and removes the need for `id`'s. You may still use them if needed later on, but for this routine they are not required.

Within `mouseclick()` we check if the click element contains the expected CSS class and when it doesn't then we add it.

Then, within `check()`:

- we store the table rows in an Array.
- loop through the array
- store all the cells, in the current row, with the expected CSS class
- then the total count is 4 we alert the user

I have added a second row to the table so that you can test multiple rows.

```js
function check() {

    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var redCells = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td[class*="red"]');
      
      if (redCells.length === 4) {
        alert("That's 4!");
      }
    }
  }


  function mouseclick(clicked) {
    if (!document.getElementById(clicked).classList.contains('red')) {      document.getElementById(clicked).classList.add('red');
    }

    check();
  }
```

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td,
th {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="10" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v10 </td>
    <td id="16" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v16 </td>
    <td id="22" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v22 </td>
    <td id="28" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v28 </td>
    <td id="34" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v34 </td>
    <td id="40" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v40 </td>
    <td id="46" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v46 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="110" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v110 </td>
    <td id="116" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v116 </td>
    <td id="122" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v122 </td>
    <td id="128" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v128 </td>
    <td id="134" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v134 </td>
    <td id="140" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v140 </td>
    <td id="146" onclick="mouseclick(this.id)"> v146 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```